# Connecting Micro USB keyboard to a Type C device

Tags: usb, keyboard

I've recently purchased a micro USB smartphone keyboard (image below).
The problem is, I'm using OnePlus 5T which has a type C USB port. I've already tried micro to type C adapters, but those didn't work.
Is there any way to make this keyboard work with a type C device?

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled USB OTG in your settings directly before connecting the keyboard (On the OnePlus it seems to be automatically disabled after some minutes if you don't use it)?

Comment: Tried it, didn't work unfortunately (assuming you meant the [OTG Storage option](https://i.imgur.com/tYa89ES.jpg))

Comment: Just bought the same android keyboard and experiencing the same issue. I tried to connect it to my old tabled which has original female micro USB and it worked on it but with the type c, it does not even recognise it. I'm going to try a couple of other adapters at the tech shop before start thinking about changing a cable on it.